# How to call a module in ThisWorkbook in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have some macros in Module1 inside modules i.e.
Module1 has:

```
Sub Macro1
   ' Code
End Sub

Sub Macro2
   ' Code
End Sub
```

Now, I want to call this entire `Module1` in the `ThisWorkbook` available within the Microsoft Excel Objects i.e.

Inside `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Sub CallingModule
     **Call Module1 (I want to call in this way)**
End Sub
```

but, this is not the correct procedure to call. Please tell me the correct procedure to call a Module.

Comment: What about calling macros in module1 one by one?

Comment: Actually I want to call the entire module. Is it possible?

Comment: No. You call specific routines, not an entire module.

Comment: I agree with @Rory here. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to call all the routines in a particular module? If yes, then it IS POSSIBLE

Answer (score 6):

Like Rory mentioned above you call specific routines, not an entire module. However if you want to call all the routines **Macro1**, **Macro2**, **Macro3** etc from a module then is it possible?

**YES**

Please note that if your `Module1` has **SIMPLE ROUTINES** as shown below then yes, it is possible to call all the procedures in a module.

Let's say you have these in `Module1`

```
Sub Sample1()
    MsgBox "I am Sample1"
End Sub

Sub Sample2()
    MsgBox "I am Sample2"
End Sub

Sub Sample3()
    MsgBox "I am Sample3"
End Sub

Sub Sample4()
    MsgBox "I am Sample4"
End Sub
```

[image]

Now simply paste this code in `Module2`. You also need to set a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility xx.xx` library.

```
'~~> Code adapted from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx
Sub CallModule1()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long, NumLines As Long
    Dim ProcName As String
    Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
    Dim MyAr() As String
    Dim n As Long

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
        ReDim Preserve MyAr(n)
            ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)

            '~~> Store the routine names in an array
            MyAr(n) = ProcName
            n = n + 1

            LineNum = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind) + _
                    .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind) + 1
        Loop
    End With

    '~~> This is where I am running every routine from Module1
    For n = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        Run "Module1." & MyAr(n)
    Next n
End Sub

Function ProcKindString(ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind) As String
    Select Case ProcKind
        Case vbext_pk_Get
            ProcKindString = "Property Get"
        Case vbext_pk_Let
            ProcKindString = "Property Let"
        Case vbext_pk_Set
            ProcKindString = "Property Set"
        Case vbext_pk_Proc
            ProcKindString = "Sub Or Function"
        Case Else
            ProcKindString = "Unknown Type: " & CStr(ProcKind)
    End Select
End Function
```

When you run the routine `CallModule1()`, then each and every procedure from Module1 will run automatically.

Comment: What a brilliantly convoluted way to run a handful of procedures - I love it!